# telebot проблемаc чатом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

не работает функционал полностью помогите найти ошибки
вот код:

main.py:

```
import telebot 

from telebot import types

from database import DataBase

import confi


db = DataBase('db.db')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(confi.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def starting(message):

  markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
  item1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Поиск собеседника')
  markup.add(item1)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать в анонимный чат ! Нажмите на поиск собеседника'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['menu'])

def menu(message):

  markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
  item1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Поиск собеседника')
  markup.add(item1)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '️ Меню'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])

def stoping(message):

  chat_info = db.get_acvtive_chat(message.chat.id)

  if chat_info != False:
    db.delete_chat(chat_info[0])

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Поиск собеседника')
    markup.add(item1)

    bot.send_message(chat_info[1], '❌ Собеседник покинул чат', reply_markup=markup)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Вы вышли из чата', reply_markup=markup)
  else:
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(' Поиск собеседника')
    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Вы не начили чат', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def text(message):

  if message.chat.type == 'private':
     if message.text == ' Поиск собеседника':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('❌ Остановить поиск')
        markup.add(item1)

        chat_two = db.get_chat()

        if db.create_chat(message.chat.id, chat_two) == False:
            db.add_queue(message.chat.id)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Идёт поиск собеседника', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            mes = 'Собеседник найден! Чтобы остановить диалог напишите /stop'
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            item1 = types.KeyboardButton('/stop')
            markup.add(item1)
            
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mes, reply_markup=markup)
            bot.send_message(chat_two, mes, reply_markup=markup)


    elif message.text == '❌ Остановить поиск':
        db.delete_queue(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '❌ Поиск остановлен, напишите /menu')

    else:
        chat_info = db.get_acvtive_chat(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(chat_info[1], message.text)

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

database.py:

```
import sqlite3
```

class DataBase():

```
def __init__(self, database_file):

    self.connect = sqlite3.connect(database_file, check_same_thread=False)

    self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()


def add_queue(self, chat_id):

    with self.connect:

        return self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO "queue" ("chat_id") VALUES(?)', (chat_id,))


def delete_queue(self, chat_id):

    with self.connect:

        return self.cursor.execute('DELETE FROM "queue" WHERE "chat_id" = ?', (chat_id,))

def delete_chat(self, id_chat):

    with self.connect:

        return self.cursor.execute('DELETE FROM "chats" WHERE "id" = ?', (id_chat,))


def get_chat(self):

    with self.connect:

        chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'queue'", ()).fetchmany(1)

        if (bool(len(chat))):

            for row in chat:

                return row[1]
        else: 

            return False


def create_chat(self, chat_one, chat_two):

    with self.connect:

        if chat_two != 0:

            self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM 'queue' WHERE 'chat_id' = ?", (chat_two,))

            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'chats' ('chat_one', 'chat_two') VALUES(?,?)", (chat_one, chat_two))

            return True
        else:

            return False


def get_acvtive_chat(self, chat_id):

    with self.connect:

        chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'chats' WHERE 'chat_one' = ?", (chat_id,))
        id_chat = 0
        for row in chat:
            id_chat = row[0]
            jls_extract_var = [row[0], row[2]]
            chat_info = jls_extract_var
        if id_chat == 0:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'chats' WHERE 'chat_two' = ?", (chat_id,))
            for row in chat:
                id_chat == [row[0], row[1]]

            if id_chat == 0:

                return False
            else:
                return chat_info
        else:
            return chat_info
```

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "не работает функционал"? Отредактируйте свой вопрос так, чтобы было понятно в чём заключается проблема и по возможности сократите код до минимально воспроизводимого примера

Comment: когда собесдник найден и я прописываю командку стоп пишет вы не начинали чат хотя я его начал

Comment: там import confi ПХХПА допиши g